# Programmatically develop search exposed filters

Tags: forms

I developed a custom module to list contents of custom tables. Now I want to have search filters much like exposed filter. My code is below

```
$items['recording'] = array(
    'title' => 'Recordings',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('recordingcrud_sort_with_pager_content'),
    'access arguments' => array('access recordings'),
);

function recordingcrud_sort_with_pager_content($form, $form_state) {
global $user;
print_r($form_state);
if (!isset($form_state['storage']['recordingcrud']['search_criteria'])) {
  return render_table(); 
} else {
    print_r($_POST);
    $filters = $form_state['storage']['recordingcrud']['search_criteria'];
    return render_table($filters);
}
```

}

In render_table function I am rendering the listing. and calling the fom

```
 $search_form = drupal_get_form('recordingcrud_search_form');
$output = drupal_render($search_form);
```

My search form and submit handler code is:

```
function recordingcrud_search_form($form, &$form_state) {
$form['search_term'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Search'),
    '#size' => 40,
    '#maxlength' => 120,
);
$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Apply',
  '#submit' => array('recordingcrud_search_form_submit'),
);



return $form;

    }

    function recordingcrud_search_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
        $form_state['storage']['recordingcrud']['search_criteria'] = $form_state['values'];
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    }
```

But this implementation I am getting the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in
>   /var/www/html/digitalFunctionalism/allprobail/includes/form.inc

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do this with the following changes.

I have changed the form method from post to get and then took the value of search term for url using `$_GET` 
Assigned action to the current page on which I am.

Changed the following code to

```
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('recordingcrud_sort_with_pager_content'),
```

to

```
'page callback' => 'recordingcrud_sort_with_pager_content',
```

and removed the second line.